# Method invocation may produce 'NullPointerException'

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-lint

I am reading from a HashMap that I have just constructed myself (so I know which keys are in there):

```java
List<UUID> cs = Arrays.asList(
        CHARACTERISTIC_A_UUID,
        CHARACTERISTIC_B_UUID,
        CHARACTERISTIC_C_UUID,
        CHARACTERISTIC_D_UUID,
        CHARACTERISTIC_E_UUID,
        CHARACTERISTIC_F_UUID,
        CHARACTERISTIC_G_UUID
);

HashMap<UUID, ReadResult> data = readDataFromBle(cs);

try {
    updateView(
            data.get(CHARACTERISTIC_A_UUID).getBoolValue(),
            data.get(CHARACTERISTIC_B_UUID).getIntValue(),
            data.get(CHARACTERISTIC_C_UUID).getIntValue(),
            data.get(CHARACTERISTIC_D_UUID).getIntValue(),
            data.get(CHARACTERISTIC_E_UUID).getIntValue(),
            data.get(CHARACTERISTIC_F_UUID).getBoolValue(),
            data.get(CHARACTERISTIC_G_UUID).getBoolValue()
    );
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    Log.e("MAIN", "Missing characteristic", e);
}
```

But Android Studio is convinced there is a problem:

[image: screenshot]

What am I supposed to do? As you can see I tried catching the `NullPointerException` but that doesn't seem to satisfy it.

Comment: well, it is suggesting that you `replace with Objects.requireNonNull(...` :)

Comment: @a_local_nobody Which *also* just throws a `NullPointerException`. What is its purpose? I haven't really understood the problem yet. Also, isn't there a solution that doesn't require boilerplate in every line?

Comment: i honestly don't know, i agree that it seems really redundant, hopefully someone can help you find a better solution to this, alternatively you could suppress the warning as it seems quite redundant and safe

Comment: @a_local_nobody Indeed I can and when I do I see that the inspection is called `ConstantConditions`. Now it makes even less sense to me.